# Add onClick with self input parameter of a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

Desired output in HTML:

```html
<input onclick="someFunction(this)"/>
```

Attempt:

```js
var input = $("<input/>");
input.attr("onclick", "someFunction(this)");
$("#body").append(input)
```

Result:

```html
<input onclick="[object Object]"/>
```

I have tried using:

```js
input.click({param: "this"}, someFunction);
```

I have also tried replacing "this" with "input". No luck.

jQuery is not a requirement, however I need this done dynamically. The above is just a sample, the actual object has more attributes.

Comment: Read docs: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I attempted examples from here and derivations from there, however I am still unable to figure it out. I keep getting the same result as above.

Comment: You can forward the event target to the function call using a lambda expression: `input.on('click', e => someFunction(e.target))` Why does it matter whether you render an attribute or create the listener in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the listener in-memory instead of adding the handler as an attribute. This version lets you wrap your event target in a jQuery object ahead of the function call.

```js
const someFunction = ($element) => {
  console.log($element.prop('class'));
}

const $input = $('<input>', { class: 'foo' })
  .on('click', (e) => someFunction($(e.target)))
  .appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if you really need to add it as an attribute, you could do the following.

```js
const someFunction = (element) => {
  console.log($(element).prop('class'));
}

const $input = $('<input>', { class: 'foo' })
  .attr('onclick', 'someFunction(this)')
  .appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

All is working from the box...

Here is example. Just click on `input`

```js
var input = $("<input/>");
input.attr("onclick", "someFunction(this)");
$("#body").append(input);

function someFunction(obj) {
  $('#result').css('color', 'red');
  console.log(obj);
}

$('#result').text(input[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="body">
  <div>This is your code:</div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

And you can also use pure jQuery. The `$(this)` is what you need.

```js
var input = $("<input id=\"xxx\"/>");
input.click(function() {
  const theInput = $(this);
  console.log(theInput[0]);
});
$("#body").append(input);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="body"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), `this` will be inherited.

`input.on('click', () => someFunction(this))`

Comment: Be aware that the lambda does not redefine `this` so you are good, but if you used `input.on('click', function() { someFunction(this) })`, you would have a scoping problem.

Comment: Ofc, yes. That's the glory of arrow functions.

Comment: In your example `this` will be not an input, maybe you wanted: `input.on('click', () => someFunction(input))`?